# Unity Physics 2D disable bounciness

Tags: unity-game-engine

I don't want reaction forces to bounce my pig to the side when it collides with a platform. Material bounciness = 0 for both platform and the pig

Anyone has an idea?

I wanted to ask before I dump physics2D and write my control mechanisms.

https://gfycat.com/GraciousHighKinkajou

Comment: Have you tried to give it some mass so it does not bounce so easily?

Comment: Yes. It does not work.

Comment: Set friction = 1 on both sides

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a Physics2D Material and modify it to not have bounciness.

[image]

And then, apply that material to the collider of the object, in this case, the pig.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was bug in my character controller script, had nothing to do with Unity. Thanks for understanding and answers :)

Comment: if your problem was "only a typo" please click Delete to save sustantial time for the overworked moderators